# Receiving KeyError: ' ' for my text based rpg

Tags: python, dsl

I'm working on a text based RPG along with a book called "Make Your Python Text Adventure", and I'm running into a bit of an issue. Currently, the map for the game is stored in a dictionary. However, when I attempt to run the program I'm getting a `KeyError: '      '` in my `world.py` file.

I've tried identifying where the `KeyError` could be coming from, as I know this is usually related to an entry in the dictionary IIRC. I'm unable to locate where this error is coming from, and from looking at the line of code that the error is referencing, I don't see where the `KeyError` could be from.

```
    for y, dsl_row in enumerate(dsl_lines):
        row = []
        dsl_cells = dsl_row.split("|")
        dsl_cells = [c for c in dsl_cells if c]
        for x, dsl_cell in enumerate(dsl_cells):
            tile_type = tile_type_dict[dsl_cell]
            row.append(tile_type(x,y) if tile_type else None)
```

Specifically, the error is getting thrown at the tile_type = tile_type_dict[dsl_cell] line.

This is the part of the main game file that is also throwing an error:

```
def play():
    print("Escape from Cave Terror!")
    world.parse_world_dsl()
    player = Player()
    while True:
        room = world.tile_at(player.x, player.y)
        print(room.intro_text())
        room.modify_player(player)
        choose_action(room,player)
```

This error is causing the game to crash on startup. It will load the intro line of text but then when the game reads the starting tile on the map, it hits the `KeyError`. If you need more of the source code in order to replicate/offer suggestions to this, please just let me know. The game is broken up into 5 different files for each aspect of the game, and the main game loop isn't located in the file that contains the code that I provided. Is this block where I should be looking to clean something up, or is it somewhere else?

The error in the world map file is as follows:

```
world.py", line 115, in parse_world_dsl
    tile_type = tile_type_dict[dsl_cell]
KeyError: '    '
```

And then in the main game file:

```
game.py", line 8, in play
    world.parse_world_dsl()
```

Not necessarily an error, but it is in reference to the `world.py` file so I thought it may be worth including.

Thank you all in advance to any help you can offer!

Comment: Find another method to check if a string is empty. `bool('        ')` returns True.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your dictionary keys are stored in this list:

```
dsl_cells = [c for c in dsl_cells if c]
```

You are getting keyword error `KeyError: '    '` which means that your key is `'    '`. This is not caught by the `if c]` part of your list comprehension. I'd try changing this line to:

```
dsl_cells = [c for c in dsl_cells if c.strip()]
```

This will get rid of the element `'    '` because `'    '.strip()` is `''`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I'm extremely new to this so that helped a lot. I may have completely missed the .strip() part of the end of the line while I was following along lol. It was around 4am and I was exhausted.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
dsl_cells = [c for c in dsl_cells if c.strip()]
```